# Burninate & blacklist [block]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We don't want [block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block) tag.

Tag Info

> Depending on the tags it's used with, it can refer to:
>
> - Blocking access to certain resources.
> - Blocks specific to the program or language its used within.
> - Blocks in a file system.

Tag excerpt

> Can refer to many different things depending on the use of other tags with it.

Do I need more reasons?

- 351 questions are tagged with [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), which refer to ruby block
- 264 questions are tagged with [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), which refer to [objective-c-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c-blocks)
- Many questions are refer to [blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocking) in the context of concurrent programming

It serves too many purposes and we need to do something.

Comment: _"It servers too many purposes"_ That seems inefficient, multi-purpose servers ;-) But yea, the tag could use some clean-up.

Comment: Sorry, I edited before realizing the intent :|

Comment: I did not intent to say it... but anyway...

Comment: Christ, that wiki summary is just...where did we keep the flamethrowers?

Comment: Saw this in the Hot Meta Posts and for a moment thought `[blocked]` was a new question status alongside `[closed]` & etc

Comment: This is an [improved version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7492839/revisions) of the wiki summary @Makoto , earlier it was..worse..

Comment: If the tag info contains "depending on" then it's got problems to begin with and a good sign it should go.

Comment: This still needs to go!

Answer (score 10):

It [sounds like this was supposed to have happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403022/did-this-burnination-request-get-blocked) and never did, at least according to the tag usage guidance:

> DO NOT USE This tag is scheduled for removal because it can refer to many different things depending on the use of other tags with it.

That being said, I agree with this burnination request and think that we should perform it now.

Answer (score 8):

Just came across this tag, and oy gevalt.

Based on the upvotes and comments (including from a mod), it looks like it should go.

Answer (score 6):

Stepping through the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/11047824), in order to be thorough:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Doesn't really apply to contents of the questions in an unambiguous way, and the tag itself is most certainly ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

A quick scan over the list of questions tagged [block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block) reveals a *wide* span of topics used with this tag. It contains everything from web request blocking, to game design, to [brain computer interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841791/can-character-driver-always-replace-block-driver-but-not-vice-versa). While the questions themselves are arguably largely on topic, it's hard to meaningfully argue that the tag itself is on-topic *because* it's so ambiguous.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. It seems that most questions tagged with [block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block) simply contain the word/ term "block" somewhere in their body, rather than the tag adding any value or specificity to the post itself.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Resounding no. The [current tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/block/info) acknowledges that it can refer to many things in wildly varying contexts.

#### In conclusion

[block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block) deserved to be burned in 2014, and still deserves as much now.