# Did this burnination request get [block]ed?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, burninate-system

The [block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block) tag has the following usage description:

> DO NOT USE **This tag is scheduled for removal** because it can refer to many different things depending on the use of other tags with it.

I also see a [burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267662/burninate-blacklist-block) from 2014.

It sounds like that tag was supposed to have been burninated, but never was.

In any case, the usage description is exactly right: this is a highly ambiguous tag that could refer to just about anything. I see questions about [routers blocking other PCs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727845/wireless-router-blocking-other-pcs), [blocks in a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787814/why-is-the-ball-not-hitting-blocks-in-my-breakout-game), and just about everything else.

Why did this burnination never take place? Can we complete it now?

**Edit:** For clarification, it is possible that the tag usage guidance was simply wrong about this point, but I'm not sure either way. (If they were demonstrably mistaken, that would also be a legitimate answer).

Comment: "An attempt to [block] this tag got [block]ed"

Comment: "don't [block] this burnination!"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some burninate request with over 20 votes not get featured?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356820/why-do-some-burninate-request-with-over-20-votes-not-get-featured)

Comment: @Magnetron Not really - my question isn't why the Meta post wasn't featured, it's why it seems like the tag was supposed to have been burninated but it wasn't.

Comment: It's not only [block] there is a [large backlog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bburninate-request%5d%20-%5bstatus-%2A%5d%20score%3a20%20is%3aq)

Comment: @Magnetron Yeah, I understand that, but it seems like this one was *actually planned* but never took place.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica well, it is not featured, so I don't think the process actually started

Comment: Also, the user that added the info in the wiki about burnination has only 2k rep, so I don't think any moderators took place in that edit.

Comment: @Magnetron It's possible that the tag information is simply mistaken (which would be a legitimate answer), but I'm not sure if it is or not. At a minimum, I'd like to understand *why* they thought that it was going to be removed and whether this was actually planned or not.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica fair enough. Retracted my close vote.

Comment: Why do you think this was "supposed to have been burninated"? Are you basing that assumption on anything other than the tag excerpt you've quoted? I'm not seeing anything to indicate the edit which added the text to the tag excerpt had any authority to indicate a burnination was actualy in process. It's also possible the user thought that having a post on Meta with >20 score was sufficient. Why would this tag have been given precedence in the burnination queue over the unknown number (at that time) with a higher score on their burnination request post?

Comment: The only person who can really answer why that text was added to the tag wiki is the person who edited it in 2015. You might be able to ask the people who approved the edit why they approved it.